# Change Task Runner Explorer command

Tags: npm, visual-studio-2019, task-runner-explorer

In Visual Studio 2019 I have installed the extension call **NPM Task Runner**.
[image: NPM Task Runner]

When I run a the build command the output is:

`cmd.exe /c npm run build --color=always`

How do I change that to:

`npm run build --color=always`

Because when I run the first one I get an error.
[image: Error]

How can I fix the error or change the command.

P.S.: When I run the command like this `npm run build --color=always` in the console it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixed the problem for me.

1. **Tools** > **Options** > **Projects and Solutions** > **Web Package Management** >
   **External Web Tools**
2. Move the **$(PATH)** entry to the 2nd position in the list by using the
   up arrow button.

[image: Comment]

Post: [Executes wrong version of nodejs](https://github.com/madskristensen/NpmTaskRunner/issues/66#issuecomment-406308778)